# What happened to the Goblin army summoned by Enri using her last horn?

Tags: overlord

In the Overlord anime, we saw Enri summoning 5000 new goblins to defeat First Prince's army. What happened to them after that fight? Did they disappear?

Comment: much like with the first horn, they are probably permanent summons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the Goblin Troops (although in the web novel the summons only last for an hour), they are permanent entities.

They along with the Troops act as guardians of Carne Village and E-Rantel. The are mentioned in passing in the epilogue of volume 11 (Dwarf craftsman arc) and volume 12 (Paladin of the Holy Kingdom Arc), chapter 2.